# How do I delete from a boost::ptr_set when I know the pointer I inserted?

Tags: c++, boost, set, boost-ptr-container

How do I delete from a `boost::ptr_set` when I know the pointer I inserted? (I have a **this** pointer to the inserted class object).

Here is a contrived example to show what I am trying to do:

```
boost::ptr_set<ServerConnection1> m_srv_conns1;

ServerConnection1 *this_ptr;
m_srv_conns1.insert(this_ptr = new ServerConnection1);
m_srv_conns1.erase(this_ptr); //It won't work!
```

Having a `this` pointer to the inserted object, how do I tell the `boost::ptr_set` to `erase(this)`? Note: I am no longer within the inserted object, but I have a pointer to it.

### Update

One of the comments was that I was not fulfilling all the requirements of `boost::ptr_set`. What are the requirements?

I think providing a `< operator` would do the trick?

### Answer

1. Change `m_srv_conns1.erase(this_ptr);` to `m_srv_conns1.erase(*this_ptr);`
2. Put the following code inside the `ServerConnection1` class:

`bool operator<(const ServerConnection1 & sc1) const`
`{`
`return (this < &sc1); //Pointer comparison`
`}`

Comment: `m_srv_conns1.erase(m_srv_conns1.find(this_ptr))`? I don't really know how `boost::ptr_xxx` work, but that's how it would look like for a normal `std::set`. Or maybe just save the iterator from the `pair<iterator,bool>` returned by `insert`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `m_srv_conns1.erase(*this_ptr);`.

Comment: That gives me about a 1000 character error messages that I don't care to sort through :(

Comment: Read the docs at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/associative_ptr_container.html. I think that you are not satisfying all the requirements for the elements of `boost::ptr_set<>`.

Comment: updated question, what are the requirements of boost::ptr_set<>?

Comment: They mention the Clonable concept: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/reference.html#the-clonable-concept. The problem is likely visible from the error message that you do not care to analyze.

Comment: Add `operator <` might do or you could just provide own *less than* functor as second parameter to the `boost::ptr_set<>`.